# Laravel 5.5 - From within an API Resource class, how do I get the underlying model class name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a Laravel 5.5 app with an [API resource class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources). How do I get the underlying model class name from within the `toArray()` method? I'm aware that you can access the properties and methods of the underlying model using `$this->` because the class will automatically proxy it to the underlying model. But how do I actually retrieve either the underlying model itself, or more importantly, the model class name? Is there a way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the constructor of the Resource class, you'll see the instance is loaded into a $resource property.

```
get_class($this->resource);
```

Comment: I wonder how we can do the opposite